# Merge two multidimensional lists into one list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
a_list = 
[['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 0], ['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 712.32], ['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 501.21].......]

b_list = 
[['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 100.01], ['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 50.01], ['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 521.79].......]
```

I need to merge `a_list` with `b_list` so it becomes:

```
combined_list =
[['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 0, 100,01], ['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 712.32, 50.01], ['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 501.21, 521.79].......]
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
a_list = [['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 0], ['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 712.32], ['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 501.21]]
b_list = [['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 100.01], ['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 50.01], ['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 521.79]]
```

Assuming `a_list` and `b_list` have the same length, and assuming the first sub-item of each item in both lists is always the same, as is true per your example, the solution is a one-liner.

```
>>> [a + [b[1]] for (a, b) in zip(a_list, b_list)]
[[['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 0, 100.01]], [['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 712.32, 50.01]], [['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 501.21, 521.79]]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much @A-B-B, this works. However, if I have 3rd list to add on like this: c_list = [['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 1.5], ['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 10.3], ['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 11.1]]. I do:[a + [b[1]+[c[1]] for (a, b, c) in zip(a_list, b_list, c_list)]. I am getting error message 'zip argument #3 must support iteration'. What do I do wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: @coding Use `[a + [b[1]] +[c[1]] for (a, b, c) in zip(a_list, b_list, c_list)]`. This worked for me. Make sure that `c_list` is a list like `a_list` and `b_list`. To understand that `zip` works, try `list(zip(range(5,10), range(10,15), range(15,20)))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip()` and unpack your data all along with a `list comprehension` like this example:

```
a = [['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 0],
 ['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 712.32],
 ['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 501.21]]

b = [['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 100.01],
 ['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 50.01],
 ['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 521.79]]

final = [[k,v,j] for (k,v),(_,j) in zip(a, b)]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 0, 100.01],
 ['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 712.32, 50.01],
 ['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 501.21, 521.79]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this, merge two list, then use defaultdict to generate new dictioanry, find same key, append the value to super_dict, then convert the dictionary to list format:

```
import collections
a_list = [['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 0], ['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 712.32], ['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 501.21]]
b_list = [['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 100.01], ['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 50.01], ['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 521.79]]
super_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

for e in a_list+b_list:
    super_dict[e[0]].append(e[1])

dictlist=list()
for key, value in super_dict.iteritems():
    dictlist.append([key]+value)
dictlist
```

Output:

```
[['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 712.32, 50.01],
 ['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 501.21, 521.79],
 ['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 0, 100.01]]
```

Comment: to get the desire output you can do `[key] + value`, which also allow to put it in a list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work. The idea is that you want to take a list, `a`, and create a dictionary with the key set to first element in each sublist of `a`. The value associated with that list is a list containing the second element in that sublist of `a`. Then we loop through the second list `b` and do the same. Finally, we iterate over the dictionary that we created, `D`, and turn that into a list.

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
b = [[1,20],[3,40],[5, 50]]
D = {}
for i in a:
    D[i[0]] = [i[1]]

for i in b:
    D[i[0]].append(i[1])

finalList = []
for d in D:
    finalList.append([d, D[d][0], D[d][1]])

print(finalList)
>>> [[1, 2, 10], [3, 4, 40], [5, 6, 50]]
```

Note, this program assumes that the two corresponding sublists are guaranteed to have equal first elements. If this is not the case or the two lists `a` and `b` are not equal, you'll need an if statement on `line 8` to check if the key value `i[0]` is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing my attempt in the mix:

```
list1 = [["a","b"],["c","d"]]
list2 = [["a","1"],["c","2"]]
list3 = [(sub + [list2[i][-1]]) for i, sub in enumerate(list1)]
#[['a', 'b', '1'], ['c', 'd', '2']]
```

This is pretty close to @A-B-B's though if zip uses enumerate.

Comment: this don't work correctly, try for example with `list2 = [["a","11"],["c","22"]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
a_list = [['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 0], ['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 712.32], ['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 501.21]]

b_list = [['2017-06-03 23:01:49', 100.01], ['2017-06-03 23:02:49', 50.01], ['2017-06-03 23:03:49', 521.79]]

combined_list = []
for index in range(3):
    x = a_list[index] + b_list[index]
    x.pop(2)
    combined_list.append(x)
print(combined_list)
```

Comment: I used the idea of looping through the indexes  and the use of the pop function to remove the items that appeared more than once . the code gives the out put you desired

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a one liner, then I thought I would throw it a try,

```
[set(item[0]).union(item[1]) for item in list(zip(a_list, b_list))]
>>>[{0, 100.01000000000001, '2017-06-03 23:01:49'}, {'2017-06-03 23:02:49', 50.009999999999998, 712.32000000000005}, {521.78999999999996, 501.20999999999998, '2017-06-03 23:03:49'}]
>>>
```

The result would be a set though. There won't be any duplication of elements.